# questions on aggregation functions

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I am trying to roll up/aggregate the records but cannot find the solution from oracle aggregation functions.

I've been playing with `LAG`, `COLLECT`, `RANK`, but couldn't find a solution yet.

I have the following table and would need to pull the last 5 user comments for the last two user actions.

From below sample, last two actions are Action2 and Action3.

```
date     | user_id | user_action | user_comment
---------+---------+-------------+-------------
5/1/2019 | USER3   | OPEN        | COMMENT0
5/1/2019 | USER1   | ACTION1     | COMMENT1
5/2/2019 | USER2   | OPEN        | COMMENT2
5/3/2019 | USER2   | ACTION2     | COMMENT3
5/4/2019 | USER3   | OPEN        | COMMENT4
5/5/2019 | USER3   | OPEN        | COMMENT5
5/5/2019 | USER4   | OPEN        | COMMENT6
5/6/2019 | USER3   | OPEN        | COMMENT7
5/7/2019 | USER3   | OPEN        | COMMENT8
5/8/2019 | USER3   | OPEN        | COMMENT9
5/9/2019 | USER3   | ACTION3     | COMMENT10
```

The point is  that User4's action should not be included.

Comment0 should not be included as it's not between Action2 and action3 even though it's the same user as Action3.

#### Expected results:

```
user_id | action  | comments
--------+---------+--------------------------------------------------
USER3   | ACTION3 | COMMENT10//COMMENT9//COMMENT8//COMMENT7//COMMENT5
USER2   | ACTION2 | COMMENT3//COMMENT2
```

Can anyone provide any tips?

Comment: What is the primary key of your table?

Comment: Have you tried to select the right comments *without* using aggregation?

Comment: No answer? How do you determine the order? How do you know that comment0 or comment1 should be considered first in the logic you describe -- since the date is the same for both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query may need some tweaking.  However, it can give you a starting point for finding a solution that
fits your requirements.  Ideas/steps: {1} Number all entries for a particular user via ROW_NUMBER(). {2} Find the last 2 actions. {3} join the 2 result sets, pick the last 5 entries, and get the comments into one row by using GROUP BY and LISTAGG().

```
select 
  UA.userid, UA.useraction
, listagg( R.usercomment, '//' ) within group ( order by R.date_ desc ) --{3}
  as comments
from (
  select -- {1}
    date_, userid, useraction, usercomment
  , row_number() over ( partition by userid order by date_ desc ) rownum_
  from useractions
) R join ( -- {3}
  select userid, useraction -- {2}
  from (
    select date_, userid, useraction
    , row_number() over ( order by date_ desc ) rownum2_
    from useractions 
    where useraction like 'ACTION%' 
  )  
  where rownum2_ <= 2 
) UA on R.userid = UA.userid      -- {3} join
where R.rownum_ between 1 and 5   -- {3} we only the last 5 entries
group by UA.userid, UA.useraction -- {3}
order by userid desc
;

-- result
USERID  USERACTION  COMMENTS                                           
USER3   ACTION3     COMMENT10//COMMENT9//COMMENT8//COMMENT7//COMMENT5  
USER2   ACTION2     COMMENT3//COMMENT2
```

[DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c4fa8c68fe2c0a512ad7754e62b39ad7)